# Autopano Giga: Leveling of an overexposed panorama (cr2 raw files)

Tags: 360-panorama, overexposure, levels

I'm trying to correct an overexposed panorama in Autopano Giga but I haven't yet found a way to really adjust the right settings.

It seems, that the problem lies in the interpretation of the CR2 Canon Raw files by Autopano. Can this be adjusted or is the correct workflow to adjust the files before in another program like Lightroom and import the files into Autopano afterwards?

To give you an idea: The tiles on the wall are not visible in the final render (tif 16bit) and cannot be restored using lightroom and Exposure Adjustment.

[image: Overexposed Image when imported into Autopano]
[image: CR2 Original file - normal exposure]

Comment: The tiles seem perfectly visible to me. Are you sure this isn't a problem with your monitor's ability to display the colors involved?

Comment: Oh so I didn't explain clearly: The photo is one of the footage files that I used, so it's one of the CR2 files I imported into Autopano Giga. When imported, the files are not exposed as well anymore but you can't even see those tiles on the wall because of the increased brightness (overexposed).

Answer (score 1):

As a long time user of Autopano Giga, I can confirm that this is in fact an issue. Not just with RAW files but any type that has a wide dynamic-range.

You do have some control and I think using the *gamma* slider can improve things quite a lot. I usually start with that first just  because it is already there in Autopano Giga. When that fails, which is more or less often, I do the development in Lightroom and then merge back the resulting images. Generally, it is not necessary to have an HDR output for the final panorama.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ATM I ended up exporting the images using lightroom presets directly into APG and stitched JPG files.

Comment: Btw: I saw that there are options in the general settings to set the exposure of raw images - i haven't tried it yet but this could be a way..